# Wildfly EJB calls to JBoss over HTTP freeze

Tags: java, http, jmeter, ejb, wildfly

I am doing a load test for EJB remote calls on Wildfly 15.0.1 using "EJB over HTTP" protocol. The JMeter Java Client Sampler is something like this:

public class LoginEJBTestSampler extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {

```
private static final String ARG_USUARIO = "username";
private static final String ARG_SENHA = "password";
private static final String ARG_FILIAL= "filial";
private static final String USER = "ejbuser";
private static final String PASSWORD = "ejbpassword";

private Context context;

@Override
public void setupTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
    if (!useCloseLookupEachRequest()) {
        abrirLookup();
    }
}

@Override
public void teardownTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
    if (!useCloseLookupEachRequest()) {
        fecharLookup();
    }
}

@Override
public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
    
    final LoginRemote service;
    final Usuario usuario;
    final UserContext userContext;
    
    SampleResult sampleResult = new SampleResult();
    sampleResult.sampleStart();
    
    try {
        if (useCloseLookupEachRequest()) {
            abrirLookup();
        }
        
        try {
            service = doRemoteLookup("MyModuleName", LoginRemote.class);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao executar lookup",e);
        }
        String username = context.getParameter(ARG_USUARIO);
        String password = context.getParameter(ARG_SENHA);
        long filial = context.getLongParameter(ARG_FILIAL);
        
        try {
            usuario = service.validarLoginSenha(username, password);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao executar validarLoginSenha",e);
        }
        
        if (usuario != null) {
            
            try {
                userContext = service.criarContexto(usuario.getIdUsuario(),filial, new Date(), Boolean.TRUE);//Freeze here
            }catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao executar criarContexto",e);
            }
            sampleResult.sampleEnd();           
            sampleResult.setSuccessful(Boolean.TRUE);
            sampleResult.setResponseCodeOK();
            sampleResult.setResponseMessage("Usuario: " + usuario.getNome()+" - Data Contexto: "+userContext.getSystemDate());
            
        } else {
            sampleResult.sampleEnd();
            sampleResult.setSuccessful(Boolean.FALSE);
            sampleResult.setResponseMessage("Usuario não retornado ");
        }
        
        if (useCloseLookupEachRequest()) {
            fecharLookup();
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        sampleResult.sampleEnd();
        sampleResult.setSuccessful(Boolean.FALSE);
        sampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e );

        try(StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()){
            e.printStackTrace( new PrintWriter( stringWriter ) );
            sampleResult.setResponseData( stringWriter.toString(),"UTF-8" );
            sampleResult.setDataType( org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.TEXT );
        }catch (Exception ignore) {}

    }
    return sampleResult;
}

private boolean useCloseLookupEachRequest() {
    return Boolean.getBoolean("teste-close-lookup-each-request");
}

private void abrirLookup() {
    try {
        String host = System.getProperty("default.host");
        String port = System.getProperty("default.port");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http://" + host + ":" + port+"/wildfly-services");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, USER);
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, PASSWORD);
                
        context = new InitialContext(props);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void fecharLookup() {
    try {
        if (context != null) {
            context.close();
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
private <T> T doRemoteLookup(String moduleName, Class<T> remoteInterface) {
    try {
        String intefaceName = remoteInterface.getName();
        String ejbName = intefaceName.substring(intefaceName.lastIndexOf('.')+1).replaceAll("Remote", "EJB");
        
        String jndiName = getRemoteJndiName(new EJBModule("MyApplicationName", moduleName),ejbName,remoteInterface);
        Object bean = context.lookup(jndiName);
        
        EJBClient.setInvocationTimeout(bean, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return (T)bean;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
    
private String getRemoteJndiName(EJBModule module, String ejbName, Class<?> remoteInterface) {
    String intefaceName = remoteInterface.getName();
    StringBuilder jndiName = new StringBuilder();
    jndiName.append("ejb:");
    jndiName.append(module.getApplicationName());
    jndiName.append("/");
    jndiName.append(module.getModuleName());
    jndiName.append("/");
    jndiName.append(ejbName);
    jndiName.append("!");
    jndiName.append(intefaceName);      
    return jndiName.toString();
}
```

}

The JMeter test have a thread group with 100 threads(users) and loop count 100

It happend that when the test is around 9000 examples finished, than the JMeter has only 1 live thread, randonly the test freezes with no server exception and no client exception.

I put a invocation timeout on the test sampler in order to verity if the server was holding the request, but no TimeoutException was thrown.

I got the stack trace by Visualvm is this:

```
    "Thread Group 1-75" - Thread t@111
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <42e4c2ef> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.httpclient.common.WildflyClientInputStream.read(WildflyClientInputStream.java:148)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.SimpleDataInput.read(SimpleDataInput.java:117)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.UTFUtils.readUTFBytes(UTFUtils.java:151)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:288)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:220)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1853)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1767)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1395)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:205)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.wildfly.httpclient.ejb.HttpEJBReceiver$1.getResult(HttpEJBReceiver.java:198)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:592)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:172)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:938)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:177)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:112)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.criarContexto(Unknown Source)
    at my.company.test.login.LoginEJBTestSampler.runTest(LoginEJBTestSampler.java:89)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.sample(JavaSampler.java:197)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

I would like to ask if someone has any idea about what is happening or what could I do in order to solve this problem. I guess could be a bug but the only thing a found on the internet like this is https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4904801 , but a don't have Red Hat Customer Account.

Comment: Some other information: If I close de context after at the end of each method execution the problem does not apear

Comment: Do you see the same freeze when running with the latest WildFly version (21.0.1)?  There have been many fixes and improvements since the version you're using (15.0.1).

Comment: I just tested on latest Wildfly 21.0.1 and didn't see any freeze. With running my test by 100 times, performing a amount of request about 1000k beeing 10k by 10k in a sequence I not faced freeze. 
In fact I'll realy need do run the application on 21.0.1 in order to using HAProxy as load balance for EJB over HTTP, tha is our main goal with this test.
Thanks @cheng

Comment: I have tested with Jmeter on loabalance that have diferent hosts on de backend... and I faced the problem again